# How to clear cached web fonts in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, cache, web

I'm trying to reproduce a bug where [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/HTTPS-EVERYWHERE) is preventing a [web font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts) from loading, but the web font seems to have been cached, preventing me from reproducing the bug.  Neither `Ctrl-Shift-R` nor clearing the browser data of "*Cached images and files*" fixes this.  I'm guessing that I have to clear "*Cookies and other site and plugin data*", but I don't want to clear my cookies.  Is there any other way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening Dev Tools (`Ctrl-Shift+J`), select the `Network` tab at the top, and then check `Disable cache`. Then refresh the page.

[screenshot of devtools open with disable cache checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNNNj.png)